# Not able to compile code with unsigned and signed overloads of a function

Tags: c++, overloading, integer-promotion

I was trying to write an overloaded function to accept both signed and unsigned integers.

Following is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

void fun(const long long a)
{
    std::cout << "Signed: " << a << std::endl;
}

void fun(const unsigned long long a)
{
    std::cout << "unsigned: " << a << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int v = 10;
    fun(v);
    return 0;
}
```

This gives the following compilation error.

```
main.cpp:17:5: error: call to 'fun' is ambiguous
    fun(v);
    ^~~
main.cpp:4:6: note: candidate function
void fun(const long long a)
     ^
main.cpp:9:6: note: candidate function
void fun(const unsigned long long a)
     ^
1 error generated.
```

I was assuming it would work just fine, as `unsigned int` can be represented by the `unsigned long long` type.

Can anyone please help me understand this error?

Comment: From C++20 an alternative to overloading would be a pair of template functions with `requires` clauses to specify that one function is only considered for signed integers and the other for unsigned integers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, an unsigned integer can be implicitly converted to an (un)signed integer of larger size without any data loss. And `(un)signed long long` is larger than an `unsigned int` in most implementations.

Since `unsigned int` is implicitly convertible to both `long long` and `unsigned long long`, the compiler doesn't know which overload you want to call, hence the error. So, you will have to explicitly tell it which overload to use, eg:

```
fun(static_cast<unsigned long long>(v));
```

Or

```
static_cast<void (*)(const unsigned long long)>(fun)(v);
```

Or

```
void (*f)(const unsigned long long) = fun;
f(v);
```